# Bind ProgressBar Color to Property Value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `ProgressBar` declared in XAML:

```
<ProgressBar Width="100" Height="15" BorderThickness="0" Value="{Binding Progress}" Maximum="{Binding Maximum}" Minimum="{Binding Minimum}"/>
```

Let's also pretend I have another property available to me via binding, `FileState` that reflects an enumeration of two states: `Complete` and `Failed`.

If the `FileState` value is `Complete` I want the `ProgressBar`'s color to be `Green`. If the `FileState` is `Failed`, I want the color to be `Red`.

Does XAML facilitate this in a declarative style?

The objective is to facilitate more `FileState`s, e.g. "In Progress", etc. I've seen a bunch of solutions like the one described in [Highlighting Items in a WPF ListView](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18585/Highlighting-Items-in-a-WPF-ListView); however, that is facilitated not by declarative XAML, but by actual code.

A derived solution from the linked article would be:

```
<ProgressBar.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <!--"2" being "Complete"-->
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FileState}" Value="2">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>    
    </Style>
</ProgressBar.Style>
```

And to repeat that for the different values. But, I don't know if that is "best practice".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, for a declarative style, the solution mentioned in the OP is best practice. If one so desired, they could further abstract out the [styles to a CommonStyles.xaml file](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pVcRMCqB-ME&index=1&list=LLEPNRHS9_H4l-8SOMnbbpxQ) and reference the style, dynamically: `< ... Style="{DynamicResource Style_Triggers}"/>`